# Quais seriam as formas de utilizar o return no JavaScript e como elas funcionam?

Tags: javascript

Acho que por mais simples que possa parecer, eu acabei não entendendo muito bem o `return` do JavaScript.

Ficaram algumas dúvidas que eu gostaria de compreender melhor, e quais seriam as melhores situações para utilizá-las.

```
function soma(valor1,valor2){
    var resultado = 0;
    resultado = valor1 + valor2;
    return resultado;
}
```

Por que quando eu uso `return` resultado o código funciona e na segunda opção não?

```
function soma(valor1,valor2){
    var resultado = 0;
    resultado = valor1 + valor2;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Porque na segunda opção você não retorna nada. A sintaxe é `return [[expression]];`. A definição da declaração é: "*A expressão cujo valor será retornado. Se omitido, undefined é retornado.*" [fonte](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

Comment: Entendi perfeitamente, então neste caso não seria conveniente utilizar um return vazio no final da função, porque não retornaria nenhum valor para mim, certo?

Comment: A primeira está retornando o resultado (retorna resultado), a segunda está saido do método (retorna apenas), vc está dizendo que dali pra frente não fará nada, veja que vc colocou o retorno no final do método... ou seja, mesmo que você coloque qualquer coisa abaixo do retorno, ele não retornará mais nada.

Comment: @IvanFerrer Obrigado, consegui compreender.

Answer (score 2):

> A declaração `return` finaliza a execução de uma função e especifica
>   os valores que devem ser retornados para onde a função foi chamada.
>   (**[Documentação MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)**)

Ao omitir no `return` a variável `resultado`, criada dentro da função, quem chamou a função não recebe nenhum valor, apenas executou a função e finalizou no `return`, que nem é necessário no final da função, já que o final da função é onde ela acaba.

O `return` (sem nada) só é útil no meio da função, quando você quer finalizar ela naquela linha.

Por exemplo:

```
function f(x){

   if(x != 1){
      return; // finaliza a função sem retornar nada
      // return x*10; // ou finaliza retornado alguma coisa
   }

   alert("alerta");

}
```

No caso acima, se a condição `x != 1` for atendida, a função termina e não chega nem no `alert`.

Mas o `return` geralmente é usado para retornar um valor criado dentro da função, como no seu primeiro exemplo.

Comment: Obrigado, consegui compreender perfeitamente. 
Quando eu coloco um valor diferente de 1 ao chamar a função, é retornado uma caixa de alerta.
Portando ao colocar o valor 1, é retornado o undefined.

Comment: Sim, foi só um exemplo. Para retornar um valor, como dito, o return deve ser seguido do valor que vc quer retornar, como no seu primeiro exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

O `return` é utilizado para retornar algo, se você não definir nada para ele, ele somente retornará uma saída do método:

```
   function soma() {

    //retorna soma 3 mais 4 => 7
    return (3 + 4);

    } 

   function verdadeOuMetira(p1, p2) {
      //retorna true (caso a soma seja 7), ou false (caso a soma seja diferente de 7)
      return ((p1 + p2) == 7);
   } 

    function soma() {
    var soma = (3 + 4);
    //retornando um valor de uma variável, retorna soma 3 mais 4 => 7
    return soma;

    } 

    function soma(callback) {

    //retorna soma 3 mais 4 => 7
    return callback();

    } 

   // passando um método callback de soma para o método de cima
      soma(function(){
            return 3 + 4;
       })
```

Para entender melhor, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
    function soma() {
    var soma = (3 + 4);
    return; //aqui você está saindo da função (pois você não definiu nenhum parâmetro para ser retornado...

    //o código foi retornado acima, então essa soma não será retornada
    return soma;

    }
```

Usando `return;`você está fazendo uma saída do código, para ter um valor de saída, pode utilizar `return false;`, neste caso você consegue testar seu método:

Exemplo:

```
function checkValor(valor) {
  //aqui você está dizendo em qual caso ele vai retornar (verdadeiro ou falso)...
  if(valor.indexOf('texto') !== -1) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
if (!checkValor('onnoon')) {
    console.log('sucesso, não existe mesmo!')
}
if (checkValor('onnoon')) {
    console.log('não é válido!')
}
if (checkValor('texto')) {
    console.log('É válido!')
}
```

Comment: Valeu, consegui compreender ainda mais com o seu exemplo. A única dúvida que fiquei, foi em relação ao trecho  "if(valor.indexOf('texto') !== -1)".

Neste caso, o que seria esse "!== -1" e não "=== -1" ou "=== 1"

Comment: == (verifica igualdade), === (verifica se é igual e se é do mesmo tipo, exemplo: boleano) a exclamação serve para negar ( ! ), (!param) é o mesmo que (param == false).

Comment: `.indexOf` retorna a posição encontrada de um texto, quando não encontra é retornado como `-1`, você pode abrir outra pergunta a respeito ou de preferência, fazer uma pesquisa no SOpt sobre isso.

Comment: Pode deixar, vou dar uma olhada nisso ai sim. Sou iniciante em javascript e to pegando as coisas aos poucos, mas todas essas dicas ai eu anotei aqui no caderno pra dar aquela "consultada" quando eu empacar lá na frente. Eu gosto muito de saber entender cada funcionalidade, antes de avançar. Obrigado pela ajuda!